# FabricJS capture the entire canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way to capture the entire canvas to a file? I have found a way to do it with the canvas itself or the last active object. I wanting to capture all of the the objects and the canvas itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply capture canvas object by:

```
JSON.stringify(canvas);
```